# How do I define a custom verbatim command?

Tags: verbatim

I'm not quite sure how to describe this, but I want to create a custom command that treats its input as verbatim and allows some control of the output.

In pseudocode, I want:

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\verb{!#1!}}
\newcommand{\samp}[1]{{\normalfont\textsl{\verb!#1!}}}
```

(But that obviously doesn't work)

`newverbs` gets me close to what I need, but e.g.

```
\RequirePackage{newverbs}
\newverbcommand{\code}{}{}
```

requires `\code!~!` rather than `\code{~}`

Comment: The main problem is that `\verb` can never be used in the argument to another command.

Comment: @egreg Exactly - what's the workaround?

Comment: There's no workaround. What's wrong in typing `\verb|something|` instead of `\code|something|`? Can you make some examples of usage of your command? Maybe there's a different way to accomplish the task.

Comment: @egreg it's less semantic - e.g. in the future I might want to automatically syntax highlight code chunks.

Comment: Well, `\let\code\verb` will do, of course. But with the same syntax as `\verb` and not as the argument of another command. In general `newverbs` is the way to go, if you want to change formatting.

Comment: If you want a reason why it cannot work, see http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin

Comment: Probably, from the `url` package, you'll find the needed code but I'm not experienced enough to extract it from there: [url.sty](http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.sty)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you interpret macro parameters as verbatim?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256983/can-you-interpret-macro-parameters-as-verbatim)

Answer (score 5):

I prepared something using the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package. You can adjust the appearance by customizing the `\lstset` and `\lstdefinestyle` commands. See the documentation for further information.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\color{red}\itshape
}
\lstdefinestyle{inline}{
    columns=fullflexible,
    breaklines=false
}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline[style=inline]!#1!}
\begin{document}
Here is some \code{verbatim} text.
\end{document}
```

The output will looks something like this

[image: Verbatim text using lstlisting]

Comment: And how badly does this blow up if you do things like `\code{1 != 0}`?

Comment: Feel free to suggest a better delimiting character than `!`

Comment: Note that newer versions of `listings` also support `\lstinline{#1}` which would not need the character-marker `!`. Also, in case if anyone is interested, I wanted to have the style like `\mathnormal`. You can do that via `basicstyle=\usefont{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}`.

Answer (score 2):

This will give inline conversion of the argument to catcode 12 tokens, except for spaces and percents (%), which it still takes as ignore-the-rest-of-the-line-characters.  Thus, it will wrap.  But what it will not do is honor linefeeds in the argument.  But as an inline command, you wouldn't want it to.

As Joseph Wright points out, unbalanced braces will also break this version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\fauxverb#1{\textsl{\detokenize{#1}}}
\begin{document}
This is \fauxverb{\verbatim} text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Won't work with for example `\fauxverb|%{|`

Comment: Remark: `\detokenize` is documented in eTeX manual. -- See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150767/strange-behaviour-with-detokenize-and-underscore for why T1 fontenc is necessary. (also it's not necessary for other engines such as XeLaTeX)