# How to do \newcommand{\filepath}[1]{\verb!#1!}?

Tags: formatting, verbatim

I want to define a command `\filepath` so that I can use `\filepath{foo_bar.cpp}` and it is printed in monospaced font.

Also, why does this not work? I get strange errors:

```
\newcommand{\filepath}[1]{\verb!#1!}
```

Comment: You can use the listings package with `\lstinputlisting`

Comment: How? It should not print the content but the filename. Like I'm trying to do in the title of the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I define a custom verbatim command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114997/how-do-i-define-a-custom-verbatim-command)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: The answer here is better than in the other question. For example, there is always a possible character where it would fail but I don't want that.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Which one? I just checked [url.sty](http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.sty) and it seems they have found a (complicated) way to read the argument verbatim (search "reading the argument verbatim").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are re-inventing the wheel. The package `url` provides a command `\path`.

```
\documentclass[obeyspaces]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

\url{aa/bb_cc/dd.foo}

\path{aa/bb_cc/dd.foo}

\path{C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The option `obeyspaces` is passed to `url` package (which is loaded by `hyperref`) so that spaces in the path are respected (see the third line in image).

Comment: That does not work in a title. But I'm using now `\newcommand{\filepath}[1]{\protect\path{#1}}` which does. Thanks!

Comment: @Albert Fragile commands need to be `\protect`ed in moving arguments. Or you may use the optional arguments for titles: `\section[short title]{{File \path{foo.cpp}}`

Answer (score 9):

perhaps the best way is to use

```
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\filepath{}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\filepath{}

\begin{document}

\url{aa/bb_cc/dd.foo}

\filepath{aa/bb_cc/dd.foo}

\end{document}
```

Note `\url` becomes clickable but not `\filepath` in the hyperref version.

Comment: I already have `hyperref` included and I use `\url` for URLs. It's almost like I want it to be for `\filepath`, except that it is clickable.

Comment: @David: This time your miracle failed ;-)

Comment: @Albert Ok so you just want the original url.sty version without the hyper support, I will just check the incantation required...

Comment: I just tested and it seems that the version from `\DeclareUrlCommand` is not clickable but other `\url`s are, so it's already like I want it. Whereby I would not have expected it to not be clickable.

Comment: @Albert it works fro me, see update

Comment: It doesn't work if it is inside of a title. Like in `\section{File \filepath{foo.cpp}}`.

Comment: @Albert `\protect\filepath`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is `\path` command provided by `url` Can you please add it to your answer so that I will delete mine :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar nah, I'll vote for yours instead (for the obeyspaces bit, mostly)