# Is there a package (or command) to escape filesystem paths?

Tags: formatting, verbatim

I see this is one option:

```
c:$\backslash$subd1$\backslash$subsubd1
```

for representing

```
c:\subd1\subsubd1
```

is there something that leaves the TeX a bit more human-readable, such as

```
\escape{c:\subd1\subsubd1}
```

Comment: Please see [How to do \newcommand{\filepath}\[1\]{\verb!#1!}?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117979)

Comment: Also, there is also `\textbackslash` which you can use instead of `$\backslash$`.

Comment: Thanks martin/marco, it was a duplicate. Not sure how my search didn't turn that up. Perhaps because I didn't include verbatim anywhere in my searches (I knew it didn't wrap the way I wanted and the lstlistings package seemed like overkill)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `url` provides also the command `\path{}`:

```
\usepackage{url}%loaded by hyperref by default
.....
\path{c:\subd1\subsubd1}
```

> [image]

Here the small MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\path{c:\subd1\subsubd1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sure we have a similar question somewhere.