# Strange behaviour with \detokenize and underscore

Tags: characters, font-encodings, detokenize

I just learned about `\detokenize`, so this question is likely a naive one.

Nonetheless, based on what I thought that I understood about `\detokenize`, I would have expected `\detokenize{_}` to render as `_`.

However, when I compile the following MWE, `\detokenize{_}` renders as something that seems to be <del>[`U+05C4`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/05c4/index.htm)</del> [`U+02D9`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02d9/index.htm) (see @Qrrbrbirlbel's comment).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

A\detokenize{_}B

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, when I add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble, everything works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

A\detokenize{_}B

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's going on here? My `.tex` file is UTF-8 encoded, and I'm compiling on a Mac (OS X 10.9.1) with TeXShop (v. 3.26) if any of that is relevant here.

Comment: There’s no `_` in the [OT1 encoding](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/encoding/ot1.htm). It is at position 0x5F (ASCII) in [T1](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/encoding/t1.htm). At this position is [`˙`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02d9/index.htm) in OT1.

Comment: Normally one doesn't load a fontencoding manually with XeTeX. Using package `fontspec` is the standard, which loads en encoding called `eu1`, giving you a *wider* support. [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984)

Comment: `\string_` is easier than `\detokenize{_}`, isn't it? But `\_` is even easier (and works also with OT1).

Comment: @egreg For me, `\string_` still produces `˙` unless `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is loaded. And `\_` isn't an option in this case. (This question arose as a result of one of [the answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149098/32888) to [my question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149086/citation-with-doi-that-has-underscore-breaks-functionality-in-bibdesk/) about DOIs and BibTeX.)

Comment: @Adam Of course: `\string_` is perfectly equivalent to `\detokenize{_}` (but more efficient).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel) points out in the comments, there is no `_` in OT1 encoding, which is the default font encoding for LaTeX.

Yet, in T1 encoding, `_` is at 5F:

[image]

Which is where `˙` is at in OT1 encoding:

[image]

Thus, without specifying the output font encoding to be T1 by declaring `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble, the output will be `˙` instead of `_`.

Comment: The code point is “5F”, not “5xF”. The ‘x’ is a placeholder in the column head.