# How does \_ work if OT1 is default encoding for LaTeX?

Tags: font-encodings

Fair warning: I know approximately zero things about fonts and font encodings, so this is perhaps another naive question on my part.

Recently, I [asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150767/strange-behaviour-with-detokenize-and-underscore) about the behavior of `\detokenize{_}`, as one needs to specify `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` for it to work as expected.

Apparently, the default font encoding for LaTeX is OT1, and there is no `_` in OT1. Thus, for something like `\detokenize{_}` or `\string_` to render as `_` and not `˙`, one must specify T1 font encoding.

Yet, [as @egreg points out in a comment on that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150767/strange-behaviour-with-detokenize-and-underscore#comment343495_150767) and as we all are likely aware, `\_` renders as `_` in LaTeX without having to do anything to the font encoding.

So, my question is how can LaTeX actually render `\_` as `_` if there is no `_` in OT1, which is the default encoding?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`plain.tex` includes

```
\def\_{\leavevmode \kern.06em \vbox{\hrule width.3em}}
```

`latex.ltx` includes

```
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textunderscore}{%
  \leavevmode \kern.06em\vbox{\hrule\@width.3em}}
```

and

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\_}{%
   \ifmmode\nfss@text{\textunderscore}\else\textunderscore\fi}
```

but `t1enc.def` includes

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textunderscore}{T1}{95}
```

so that the actual underscore from the font is used if T1 is loaded. In that case, the `\DeclareTextSymbol` from `t1enc.def` overrides the default meaning of `\textunderscore` from `latex.ltx` and, hence, of `\_`. If T1 is not loaded, of course, and OT1 is used, the default definition is not overridden and TeX essentially fakes the underscore when `\textunderscore` or `\_` is typeset.