# Define a special verbatim commmand

Tags: tex-core, verbatim, plain-tex, braces

To learn more about Plain TeX, I try to define a special verbatim command `\verb{code}`, which puts `code` inside braces.

When there is no braces in `code`, It's easy. But when there are some **balanced** braces inside `code`,  it seems hard to define this command.

Furthermore, there may be some `\{` or `\}` inside `code`. How could I define this?

For example, I want `\verb{a{b\}c\{d}e}` to produce `a{b\}c\{d}e`.

Comment: Due to the way TeX reads tokens, it's difficult to do this in a command. You might want to take a look at `\tt\makeatletter\meaning\@sverb` (just typeset that). It's not that practically helpful, but it shows the complexity.  You have to change catcodes, so taking in the argument (as you would naturally do) doesn't *work* since everything is already read by that time. You have to take in a delimiting argument, then change catcodes accordingly. Then you can do what you need.

Comment: @SeanAllred You have to change the catcodes before grabbing the delimited argument ;-)

Comment: @Z.H. While there are approaches that would allow the interface you suggest, they are pretty complex (we do something related in the LaTeX `xparse` package for grabbing optional arguments, and tracking nested brackets is tricky). As already suggested, a _much_ easier approach is to use some think `\verb"a{b\}c\{d}e" where the very first character after `\verb` is used as both the start and end marker. Would a solution working in this way be acceptable?

Comment: @JosephWright I know how to define `\verb` just like it is in LaTeX. I'm just curious about more.

Comment: I had proposed an answer with `\detokenize`, but deleted it after Joseph pointed out your focus was plain TeX.  If you want the answer resurrected, just let me know.

Comment: You'll have problems when there are ***unbalanced*** braces. It's impossible to grab an argument with unbalanced braces, of course: you'd have to tell in some way which one is the final. All in-line verbatim macros that allow braces in the text to be typeset verbatim use the convention of delimiting the text with a character not used in the text itself. You can find good definitions of in-line verbatim macros in the TeXbook and in TeX by Topic.

Comment: @egreg Yes, but since almost all of the time we just put **balanced** braces inside `code`, Let's assume braces are always **balanced** and don't consider **unbalanced** case.

Comment: it's easier to come up with a `\begin ... \end` or a "toggle" approach than a command-with-argument definition.  you might find the definitions of `\verbatim` and `|...|` in the file `tugboat.sty` (the plain *tugboat* implementation) interesting.  these extended the *texbook* definitions to pay attention to spaces at the beginning of a line, and an "escape" to allow metacode within a verbatim block, among other features.  this file (and related material) is in tex live in the `.../plain/tugboat-plain/` area.

Comment: For LaTeX see also [How do I define a custom verbatim command? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114997/how-do-i-define-a-custom-verbatim-command)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is more simple solution:

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\catcodeletters{\tmpnum=64
  \loop \advance\tmpnum by1 
     \ifnum\tmpnum<128
        \ifnum\catcode\tmpnum=11 \catcode\tmpnum=12 \fi
     \repeat 
}
\def\verb{\bgroup\catcode`\%=12\catcode`\^=13\catcode`\ =12\catcode`\#=12
   \catcodeletters\verbA}
\def\verbA#1{\def\tmp{#1}\tt\expandafter\mm\meaning\tmp\endmm\tmp\egroup}
\def\mm#1->#2\endmm{\def\tmp{#2}}

\verb{a{b\}c\{d}e a  #sp_&ace}

\end
```

I've added the `\catcodeletters` to my macro in order to spaces after `\foo` don't arise. Thanks to Heiko.

Edit: My 12-lines macro was not chosen as an accepted answer but 50-line macro was. May be that the spacemarks replaced by real spaces was the core of the interest, but it was not specified in the question. This is a part of printing, no scanning verbatim. So it can be implemented after `\tmp` is scanned. You can change `\verbA` definition and you can add the `\printverb` macro, which does the space replacement by another way than in the previous answer.

```
\def\verbA#1{\def\tmp{#1}\expandafter\mm\meaning\tmp\endmm
   \tt\expandafter\printverb\tmp\end\egroup}

\def\printverb{\futurelet\next\printverbA}
\def\printverbA{%
  \ifx\next\end \def\next{\let\next}%
  \else \ifx\next\spacetoken \char32
            \def\next{\afterassignment\printverb\let\next= }%
        \else \next \def\next{\afterassignment\printverb\let\next}%
  \fi   \fi
  \next
} 
\edef\tmp{\let\noexpand\spacetoken= \space}\tmp
```

Now the `\tt\char32` spacemarks are printed instead spaces.

Comment: I'd add also ``\catcode`\\=12`` or control sequences will get a space after them.

Comment: @egreg OK, but the `\catcode``\\=12` brings new problem: the `\{` and `\}` sequences cannot be written arbitrary out of matching braces...

Answer (score 7):

A plain TeX solution without e-TeX.

1. The argument is read with verbatim category codes (12).
   Plain TeX provides a list of special characters in `\dospecials`.
2. The argument is surrounded by curly braces. Therefore the curly braces
   gets their usual category codes. Then the argument may contain balanced curly braces. However it is not possible to escape a curly brace with a backslash, because the backslash has category code 12.
3. The argument is read and stored in a macro `\verbText`.
4. `\meaning` prints the macro definition. The characters have the category code 12 (other) and the space character has its normal category code 10 (space).
5. Font `\tentt` has a special space character, but the space needs a different catcode. This is done by macro `\ConvertSpacesToCatcodeOther`.

Example file:

```
\def\verb{%
  \begingroup
  % verbatim catcodes
  \def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }%
  \dospecials
  % except curly braces
  \catcode`\{=1 %
  \catcode`\}=2 %
  \verbAux
}
\def\verbAux#1{%
  \def\verbText{#1}%
  \edef\verbText{%
    \expandafter\StripPrefix\meaning\verbText
  }%
  \tentt
  \FirstOfOne{\expandafter\ConvertSpacesToCatcodeOther\verbText} \NIL
  \endgroup
}
\def\StripPrefix#1>{}
\long\def\FirstOfOne#1{#1}
\def\ConvertSpacesToCatcodeOther#1 #2\NIL{%
  #1%
  \def\temp{#2}%
  \ifx\temp\empty
    \expandafter\Gobble
  \else
    \SpaceOther
    \expandafter\FirstOfOne
  \fi
  {\ConvertSpacesToCatcodeOther#2\NIL}%
}
\long\def\Gobble#1{}
\begingroup
  \lccode`\9=32 % space
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\SpaceOther{9}%
}

\verb{a{b\}c\{d}e  with spaces}

\bye
```

> [image: Result]

### Escaping

Also the escaping of the curly braces with a backslash can be implemented.
If the backslash has its escape category code (0), then command names are tokenized as usual. `\meaning` will add a space after command names that consists of characters with letter catcodes (11). `\abc` would become `\abc␣`. This can be avoided by changing the category codes for all letters:

```
\def\verb{%
  \begingroup
  % verbatim catcodes
  \def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }%
  \dospecials
  % except curly braces and backslash
  \catcode`\\=0 %
  \catcode`\{=1 %
  \catcode`\}=2 %
  \count255=`\A %
  \loop
    \catcode\count255=12 %
  \ifnum\count255<`\Z %
    \advance\count255 by 1 %  
  \repeat
  \count255=`\a
  \loop
    \catcode\count255=12 %
  \ifnum\count255<`\z %
    \advance\count255 by 1 %  
  \repeat
  \verbAux
}
\def\verbAux#1{%
  \def\verbText{#1}%
  \edef\verbText{%
    \expandafter\StripPrefix\meaning\verbText
  }%
  \tentt
  \FirstOfOne{\expandafter\ConvertSpacesToCatcodeOther\verbText} \NIL
  \endgroup
}
\def\StripPrefix#1>{}
\long\def\FirstOfOne#1{#1}
\def\ConvertSpacesToCatcodeOther#1 #2\NIL{%
  #1%
  \def\temp{#2}%
  \ifx\temp\empty
    \expandafter\Gobble
  \else
    \SpaceOther
    \expandafter\FirstOfOne
  \fi
  {\ConvertSpacesToCatcodeOther#2\NIL}%
}
\long\def\Gobble#1{}
\begingroup
  \lccode`\9=32 % space
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\SpaceOther{9}%
}

\verb{a{b\}c\{d}e  with spaces \abc\} \{}

\bye
```

> [image: Result with escaping]