# How to use \verb or something similar inside a \newcommand

Tags: macros, errors, verbatim

The command `\displaygraphics[width-1in]{figure=some_fig.pdf}` will display a graphic.  Sometimes I want to typeset when I do not have the graphics files available, so I want to do something like:

```
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1][]{\verb|#2|}
```

The intention is that it will simply display the name of the file to be used, rather than try to display the graphic.  Note graphics names have underscores, which is the reason I would want something like verbatim.  So the command
`\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1][]{#2}` does not work.

Of course the solution above does not work either, since `\verb` cannot be used like this inside a `\renewcommand`.  How do I do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. You can format code inline by enclosing it in back-ticks, or by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon. Larger chunks of code can be similarly selected and will be marked up with a preceding 4 spaces. (BTW, do you mean `\includegraphics`?

Comment: Apart from the macro name and the error in the number of arguments, `\verb` cannot be used in the argument to another macro, even `\newcommand`.

Comment: See also [How do I define a custom verbatim command? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114997/how-do-i-define-a-custom-verbatim-command) for more general solutions.

Answer (score 6):

The reason your redefinition doesn't work is that you are specifying the wrong number of arguments in the `\renewcommand`. If I understand your question correctly you just want filename placeholders for your images.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{\begin{center}\texttt{\detokenize{#2}\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Path/to/your/image/file}
\caption{When I finally get the file this will be a cool image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Alternatively, you can use the `[demo]` option of `graphicx` which will replace any `\includegraphics` command with a black box as below. In this case, of course, you don't get the filenames printed out, but you also don't need to redefine `\includegraphics`.

[image: output of demo]

Comment: I've seen a draft document that doesn't add the black box but the name of the file; I don't remember how that was done, though.

Comment: @Manuel `draft` mode only prints the name of the file if it exists, otherwise it throws an error.  `demo` mode ignores files altogether.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of errors in your code:

```
\renewcommand{displaygraphics}[1][]{\verb|#2|}
```

1. The first argument to `\renewcommand` must be a macro name (with the backslash (fixed in the question).
2. The command to redefine is `\includegraphics` (fixed in the question)
3. The number of arguments should be 2, not 1: when another pair of brackets follows, the contents is the default value of the optional argument, which is denoted by `#1` in the replacement text; you also want a mandatory argument, which makes two.
4. `\verb` cannot be used in the argument to another macro.

Solution:

```
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\texttt{\detokenize{#2}}}
```

This will also allow underscores.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more helpful to leave `\detokenize` out? If there's any macro it would expand.

Comment: @Manuel The OP says that underscores are expected.

Answer (score 3):

What about first check `\IfFileExists` and if already  there, simply  `\includegraphics` or otherwise, for underscores and long paths as well,  in teletype style, better use an `\url`?

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip1em

\newcommand\extimg[1]{
\IfFileExists{#1}
{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{#1}} 
{\fboxsep1em\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2em}{\url{#1}}}}}

\begin{document}

Some already made image:

\extimg{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.jpg}

Some image to do:

\extimg{/home/Richard/my_funny/proyect/more_carpets/and_more/images/todo_tomorrow/my_image.jpg}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  detokenize was the thing that I was missing.  All the other suggestions are very useful as well.

Comment: @RichardHartley  You are welcome. Then, please accept the best detokenizing answer in your opinion (i.e., click in the gray checkmark  under the votes of that answer). But note that these only fix your original approach that do not allow check what images are missing, and you need re-edit the source to remove your macro after providing the images. Then, if you do not already have  all the images, you will get  a "nice" error message in the log instead of a preliminary draft.